# Eclipse RCP, RAP, how to populate tree from another view on plugin loaded

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

I want to make a dynamic application and I want to add `TreeItem`'s in a `Tree` when another plugin is loaded.

For example:

1. I have plugin: `com.project.startup` and this plugin has a `View` with a `Tree` inside it. This
2. I have plugin: `com.project.populator`. I want to populate the `Tree` from `com.project.startup` when `com.project.populator` is starting

I know how to add items but I don't know when and where I have to write my code.

So far I did this using `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup` but I get this error:

```
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ro.project.populator.TreePopulator.earlyStartup(TreePopulator.java:18)
```

My code looks like this:

```
public class TreePopulator implements IStartup
{

    @Override
    public void earlyStartup()
    {
        ViewMenuOffers viewMenuOffers = (ViewMenuOffers) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView(ViewMenuOffers.ID);
        TreeViewer treeViewer = viewMenuOffers.getTreeViewer();
        Tree tree = treeViewer.getTree();
        TreeItem trtmItem = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
        trtmItem.setText("Item 1");
    }
}
```

I think the TreeViewer is not initialized.. but it is in `createPartControl` of `ViewMenuOffers`.

How can I make this work? How can I add something to a `View` from another plugin onStartup?

Comment: You're registering an early startup plugin - there's no guarantee that your `earlyStartup()` method will be called when the workbench is open or has an active page.  You could schedule a new `Job` - the `JobManager` will be started as soon as the workbench has opened, and you can do your work in there, which should guarantee that the UI is running when you are called.

Comment: I am doing the same thing but with a `job` and now I get this error: `An internal error occurred during: "Visits: Populate menu".
No context available outside of the request service lifecycle.`

Comment: See the RAP FAQ -> http://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/FAQ#No_context_available_outside_of_the_request_service_lifecycle

Comment: can you give me an example? I can't find any...

Comment: @Tom Seidel not working even with that solution

Comment: Alex:  if you've got a solution, you should write this as an answer then accept it for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer. It can be done like this:

```
public class TreePopulator implements IStartup
{

    @Override
    public void earlyStartup()
    {
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                ViewMenuOffers viewMenuOffers = (ViewMenuOffers) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView(ViewMenuOffers.ID);
                TreeViewer treeViewer = viewMenuOffers.getTreeViewer();
                Tree tree = treeViewer.getTree();

                TreeItem trtmS = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
                trtmS.setText("Test");

            }

        });

    }

}
```